# Wrong controls initialed on page refresh

Tags: orbeon

https://gist.github.com/773373

Non relevant fields are initialized on page refresh.

Steps to reproduce

1. Access the page. Notice the two alerts. "init - uncheck" and "enabled - uncheck".
2. Select the check box. Check control is initialized. Two alerts again. This control was not relevant previously.
3. Refresh the page (I am using firefox). Notice the non-relevant control is initialized but the relevant control is not. You can tell from the alerts.

Interestingly the right component is shown but xforms-enabled is called on the wrong component.

Answer (score 0):

Getting those 2 alerts for the non-relevant control on page refresh is normal. However, after those, you should also get alerts for the newly relevant control. I created a [bug](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=315751&group_id=168&atid=350207) for this, and will update this response when the issue is fixed.

When you do a reload (ctrl-r) on Firefox, the HTML is in its initial state, as it was the first time the page was loaded. However, since Firefox resets the form fields to their value before the reload, we can detect with JavaScript that a reload happened, and the browser can ask the server "please tell me everything I need to do on the initial HTML to put it back to state X".  The server resends all the events it sent when you clicked on the checkbox, except the `<xxf:script>`, which is responsible for your script running, hence the behavior you observe.

We did some brainstorming on this issue, and described [a solution](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/projects/xforms/browser-back#TOC-Full-state-of-the-page-is-not-resto), which at this point still need to implement.

Comment: Except that the server cannot have any knowledge of <xxf:script> at that time! I have summarized the problem here: http://goo.gl/2nnKQ

Comment: Thank you Alex and Erik. Any chance for this to make it into 3.9?

Comment: Binesh, most likely this won't make it in 3.9, which we'd really like to get out of the door. However, now at least we have a solution, which wouldn't be too hard to implement. I edited by response above to link to the wiki where you can find more about what it would look like.